# Xamarin ActionBar hamburger menu spacing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add some spacing between the left edge of the app and the hamburger menu icon found in the ActionBar. I've tried the following in styles to no avail.

```
<style name="Theme.ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">50dip</item>
</style>
```

[image: need spacing!]

Thanks!